# SIP2 Checksum Calculation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, checksum

I'm working on a REST interface to a library system that uses the SIP2 protocol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Interchange_Protocol) and was able to get things working on a system that doesn't require error correction without a problem.  However, my code is now talking to another system that requires checksums, described as so in the specification:

"To calculate the checksum add each character as an unsigned binary number, take the lower 16 bits of the total and perform a 2's complement.  The checksum field is the result represented by four hex digits."

I've taken a few runs at this but not matter what I do I can't get a checksum back that matches my example message.  I'm probably making this harder than it should be (seems like it would be easier in a lower-level language with proper binary types, etc.).  Here's my latest attempt:

```
var checksum = 0;
var message = "63AOAA21221021780249|AD9999|AY0AZ";

// add each character as an unsigned binary number
for(var i=0;i<message.length;i++){
    checksum += message[i].charCodeAt();
}

console.log("character sum: " + checksum);

// take the lower 16 bits of the total
checksum = checksum.toString(2);
console.log("character sum binary representation: " + checksum);
while(checksum.length < 16){
    checksum = "0" + checksum;
}
checksum = checksum.substr(0,16);
console.log("lower 16 bits of character total: " + checksum);

// convert to dec
checksum = parseInt(checksum,2);
console.log("checksum dec: " + checksum);

// perform 2's complement
checksum = (checksum  & 0xFFFF) * -1;
console.log("2s complement: " + checksum.toString(2));

// convert to 4 hex digits
checksum = dec2hex(checksum);
console.log("checksum hex: " + checksum);

function dec2hex(i) {
   return (i+0x10000).toString(16).substr(-4).toUpperCase();
}
```

The expected checksum for the string above is "F39A".

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get there, it's probably not the most elegant approach, and certainly not high-performance, but it works reliably.

Here's the code should some other unfortunate soul find themselves looking to answer this question.  I'm plan to bundle this up with some other SIP2-related bits in a library, but for now here's a function that will generate the checksum.

```
 function sip2_checksum(message){

    var checksum_int = 0;
    var checksum_binary_string = "";
    var checksum_binary_string_inverted = "";
    var checksum_binary_string_inverted_plus1 = "";
    var checksum_hex_string = "";

    // add each character as an unsigned binary number
    for(var i=0;i<message.length;i++){
            checksum_int += message[i].charCodeAt();
    }

    // convert integer to binary representation stored in a string
    while(checksum_int > 0){
            checksum_binary_string = (checksum_int % 2).toString() + checksum_binary_string;
            checksum_int = Math.floor(checksum_int / 2);
    }

    // pad binary string to 16 bytes
    while(checksum_binary_string.length < 16){
            checksum_binary_string = "0" + checksum_binary_string;
    }

    // invert the binary string
    for(var i=0;i<checksum_binary_string.length;i++){
            var inverted_value = "X"; // something weird to make mistakes jump out
            if(checksum_binary_string[i] == "1"){
                    inverted_value = "0";
            } else {
                    inverted_value = "1";
            }
            checksum_binary_string_inverted += inverted_value;
    }

    // add 1 to the binary string
    var carry_bit = true;
    for(var i=checksum_binary_string_inverted.length - 1;i>=0;i--){
            if(carry_bit){
                    if(checksum_binary_string_inverted[i] === "0"){
                            checksum_binary_string_inverted_plus1 = "1" + checksum_binary_string_inverted_plus1;
                            carry_bit = false;
                    } else {
                            checksum_binary_string_inverted_plus1 = "0" + checksum_binary_string_inverted_plus1;
                            carry_bit = true;
                    }
            } else {
                    checksum_binary_string_inverted_plus1 = checksum_binary_string_inverted[i] + checksum_binary_string_inverted_plus1;
            }
    }

    // convert binary string to hex string and uppercase it because that's what the gateway likes
    checksum_hex_string = parseInt(checksum_binary_string_inverted_plus1,2).toString(16).toUpperCase();

    return checksum_hex_string;
 }
```